# CSS Flexbox: a centered child overflows a parent with position fixed

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow, css-position, margin

How can I properly center the `#content` without overflowing the `#container`? `margin: auto` kinda works, but looks like a hack to me, I would like not to use any margins with CSS Flexbox.

Keep in mind that the `#container` has `position: fixed`.

Here's the code demonstrates the issue: **[[View in JSFiddle ↗]](http://jsfiddle.net/9b2br2nz/1/)**

```js
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = [...Array(100).keys()].join('<br>')
```

```css
#container {
  position: fixed;
  background: lightblue;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

#content {
  border: 1px solid green;
  /* uncomment the hack below to get desired behavior */
  /* margin: auto */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Desired behavior you can check with uncommenting `margin: auto`, question is how to achieve the same result with only `flex-` properties and without `margin: auto`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a markup change you can't, as when using `align-items: center`, it by design [overflow in both directions](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-align-items-center) if the content exceed the flex container.

> ***‘center’***
>     The flex item’s margin box is centered in the cross axis within
> the line. (If the cross size of the     flex line is less than that of the
> flex item, it will overflow equally in both directions.)

Also note that [`auto` margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins) has a special meaning in Flexbox, and it is *not* a hack, quite the opposite, so in this case, they are the flex based solution to accomplish exactly that.

*Update: Here's a later answer of mine, showing a few more solutions, inlcuding the new `safe` keyword: [Flexbox align-items overflow text get cuts off at top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48876120/flexbox-align-items-overflow-text-get-cuts-off-at-top/48879161#48879161)*

```js
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = [...Array(100).keys()].join('<br>')
```

```css
#container {
  position: fixed;
  background: lightblue;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;

  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

#content {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I see. Thanks @LGSon for the detailed answer with links to specs!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have taken one parent div of `content` id and give `height:100vh` to `content_wrap` class.

```js
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = [...Array(100).keys()].join('<br>')
```

```css
#container {
  position: fixed;
  background: lightblue;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

#content {
  border: 1px solid green;
  /* uncomment the hack below to get desired behavior */
  /*margin: auto ;*/
}
.content_wrap  {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="content_wrap">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the additional wrapper is not an option. I would like to keep HTML markup as-is now.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `align-items: center;` to `align-items: left;` in your css

because you are using flex and `align-items: center;` div is showing from center part so just replace it with left.

```js
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = [...Array(100).keys()].join('<br>')
```

```css
#container {
  position: fixed;
  background: lightblue;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  display: flex;
  /*align-items: center;*/
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

#content {
  border: 1px solid green;
  /* uncomment the hack below to get desired behavior */
  /* margin: auto */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content" class="mx-auto">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In that case the `#container` won't be centered as desired: http://jsfiddle.net/9b2br2nz/2/

Answer (score -1):

you can set the `position` of the `#content` as `absolute` and set `top: 0;` in the style, here0s a working [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/uMw5sCZzWfdUdhsCfAIU?p=preview)

Comment: Absolute positioning is so wrong. Flexbox is here to get rid of it, bringing it back is a bad idea.