# Centering Content With Max Width and Without Using Margins

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, constraints

I need to center a set of children in a container.

My requirements are:

1. Each child needs a gutter to its left and right.
2. I cannot set a margin or padding on the container.
3. I cannot set padding on the children, but I can set margins.
4. Each child should have a space/gutter to its left and right.
5. Each child can have a different max-width set.
6. If the child's max-width is greater than the container width, it should take up the full width (minus its gutters).
7. If the child is narrower than the container it should be centered.
   I thought I would be able to achieve this with flexbox, because `align-items: stretch;` respects max-widths, however it will not center the children.

I cannot use `margin: 0 auto;` because I need to use the childrens' margins to set up the gutters to their left and right.

Here is my attempt using flexbox:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 600px;
  outline: 1px dashed black;
  box-
}

section {
  min-height: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

section + section {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
  
.s1 {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 100px
}
  
.s2 {
  background-color: blue;
  max-width: 200px
}
  
.s3 {
  background-color: green;
  max-width: 300px
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class='s1'></section>
  <section class='s2'></section>
  <section class='s3'></section>
</main>
```

Is there any way to reliably achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, though you need to give the `section` a width, and use `align-items: center`

To preserve the gutter when a child reach its parent's width, you can use `CSS calc()`, and do e.g. `width: calc(100% - 40px);`, and since a narrower child is always centered, you should be able to drop the `margin-left/right` as well (and if, you will be able to use auto margins).

Do note, using [`align-items: center` can cause overflow issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48876120/flexbox-align-items-overflow-text-get-cuts-off-at-top/48879161#48879161) if not using the `safe` keyword, and using *auto margins* solves that being more cross browser than `safe`.

Stack snippet

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 600px;
  outline: 1px dashed black;
}

section {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  min-height: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

section + section {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
  
.s1 {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 100px
}
  
.s2 {
  background-color: blue;
  max-width: 200px
}
  
.s3 {
  background-color: green;
  max-width: 700px
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class='s1'></section>
  <section class='s2'></section>
  <section class='s3'></section>
</main>
```

---

If you are able to drop the fixed margins, here's how using *auto margin*.

Stack snippet

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 600px;
  outline: 1px dashed black;
}

section {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  min-height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

section + section {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
  
.s1 {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 100px
}
  
.s2 {
  background-color: blue;
  max-width: 200px
}
  
.s3 {
  background-color: green;
  max-width: 700px
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class='s1'></section>
  <section class='s2'></section>
  <section class='s3'></section>
</main>
```

Comment: @SudiptoRoy Maybe...I might have misread it, and using `calc(100% - gutter)` will fix that

Answer (score 1):

If you replace your `max-width` of the children with `width`, you can achieve what you are trying to. But I don't know if there is any limitation to do this change.

Add these rules to all sections

```
section {
  max-width: calc(100% - 40px);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And if you replace `max-width` of `.s1, .s2 and .s3` with `width` you can completely omit the style-rule of the `main`.